# Shuffle: Why is a for loop switching arr[i] with arr[r] (r: random 0 - length - 1) not a uniformly random shuffle?

Tags: random, probability, shuffle

I am currently taking Sedgewick's algorithms course on Coursera (taught in Java). He says to create a uniformly random shuffling algorithm, I must go through each index `i` in my array, swapping that element with a random element FROM ONLY THOSE ELEMENTS I've ALREADY LOOKED OVER. He says if I were to swap the element with a random element out of the entire array, it wouldn't be uniformly random. Why not? If for every iteration element[I] is swapped at complete random with another element in the array, including itself, than 1/N is always the probability of where element[I] will end up; I don't see how bias is introduced.

In other words he advocates:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * i + 1)
  swap(r, i);
}
```

over

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
  swap(r, i);
}
```

Excuse the JavaScript as I am a brand new programmer and am more comfortable with it.:)

Comment: The bias comes from elements `0…i` already having been swapped somewhere else. You need to take into account what the previous iterations did to compute the probabilities for locations after all iterations, instead of looking at each swap on its own.

Comment: Read [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) for a very nice explanation.

Comment: If efficiency isn't a major concern, one straightforward way to shuffle uniformly is to keep grabbing elements randomly and copy them into a new list if and only if they haven't already been copied there.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple math. If you switch every element with another from the whole set, you'll end up getting a random number from 0 to N-1, N times, and so there are N ** N possible outcomes. Since there are N! (i.e. factorial N) possible arrangements of the items, and N ** N is not divisible by N!, some arrangements will happen more often than others.

A proper shuffle will, on the first pass, pick a random number from 0 to N-1, then the next pass 0 to N-2, etc., finally 0 to 1. That way there will be exactly N! possible outcomes, each one of the possible permutations (assuming you did the swaps correctly).